# Looking for approach to use GraphQL data to display markers in MapBox

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am building simple ReactJS webapplication that would display a map with markers inside. The webapplication is build with GatsbyJS project and data from WordPress using GraphQL. The data from Wordpress is individual posts that contain latitude and longitude coordinates. 
I would like to display each of these points from WordPress as a marker in Mapbox. Since I got more than 1.000 markers, I figured that it is optimal that I load a geojson object as the source of my map data instead of individually rendering each marker as a react component.

I would like to collect my data trough GraphQL using a static query and then build a geojson object using that data. The geojson is then received as a prop by my map component and rendered.

In practice, does this seem like the correct approach or would you suggest me another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach works, but you probably want to use a query in `gatsby-node.js` to build a static file from the data at build time rather than using a static query. This allows you to use either a direct `import` statement to include the geojson data as part of your webpack chunks, or implement a lazy loaded solution where you render a skeleton or “loading” state while issuing a separate request to get the geojson file.